# Nestjs GraphQL schema first - how to add the property resolvers for a union type?

Tags: graphql, union, nestjs

I need some help here, I can't manage to make this work.

I use NestJs with GraphQL - schema first.

I have the the following schema:

```
type Small {
    id: Int
    name: String
    color: String
}

type Big {
    id: Int
    name: String
    size: Int
}

type Huge {
    id: Int
    name: String
    engine: Int
}

type Cars {
    id: Int
    name: String
    type: Types
}

union Types = Small | Big | Huge

type Query {
    car(id: ID!): Cars
}
```

Can you please tell me how to create the resolvers for the **type** field, that is of type **Types**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. The issue was adding the resolve type function to determine the object type to be returned. After some lost/won battles, I found out you need to create a separate resolver for the union type class and one in the other resolver for the field that has the union type. So considering my example above I needed to:
1. Create a resolver for the Types type:

```
@Resolver('Types')
export class TypesResolver {
    @ResolveProperty()
    __resolveType(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Small) {
            return 'Small';
        }
        if (obj instanceof Big) {
            return 'Big';
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

2. Resolve the property used in the Cars resolver that has the Types type, and return the object required:

```
@ResolveProperty('type')
__resolveType(obj): any {
    if (obj.color) {
        return this.smallService.getByColor(obj.color);
    }
    if (obj.size) {
        return this.bigService.getBySize(obj.size);
    }
    return null;
}
```